# How does the community user work?

Tags: support, community-user

I simply can't get my head around how the Community user works.

Is it a daemon process running in the background, responsible for approving / rejecting edits, poking old questions, etc., or how else does it work?

Thanks.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Oops, didn't see that.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian It still doesn't explain how the Community user works though, from a programmatical point of view.

Comment: There is no such user. There are too many different processes to enumerate, but if anything needs a 'user' column in the database and there is no user, Community gets the blame.

Comment: @MartijnPieters An answer posted with more detail would definitely be helpful.

Comment: Suggested edit from anonymous is accepted? Community is assigned the edit. Automated edits to bump a question? Community what dunnit, etc.

Comment: No, because the dupe gives a sufficient overview already.